# How to filter "productive" amino acid sequences

Tags: python, r, sequence, fasta

I have a fasta file with different amino acid sequences, for

example : `example.fasta` :

```
>abc
HSTSDSAQTMFPVALLLLAAGSCVKGEQLTQPTSVTVQPGQRLTITCQVSYSLGTYFTAW
IRQPAGKGLEWIGMRSTGASYYKDSLKNKFSIDLDTSSKTVTLNGQNVQPEDTAVYYCAR
APSRGFDYWGKGTMVTITSATPKGPTVFPL

>def
TARQIQHKPCFL*LCCCWQLDHV*RVNS*HSRPL*LCSQVNV*PSPVRSLILLVPTSQLG
SDSLQEKDWSGLE*DLLELHTTKIH*RTSSVST*TLPAKL*L*MDRMCSLKTLLCITVPE
RPVGVLTTGGKAPWSPSPRPPQRDQLCFL*

>ghi
GSQHVRFSTNHVSCSSAAVGSWIMCEG*TVDTADLCDCAARSTSDHHLSGLLFSW*LLHS
LDQTACRKRTGVDWEQIYWSCILQRFIKEQVQYRLRHFQQNCDSKWTECAA*RHCCVLLC
QTTGSGSWLLGERHHGHHHLGHPKGTNCVSS
```

and I want to filter out the sequences that are "productive" from the "non-productive" ones.

Additional info: I had translated every DNA sequence to amino acid sequence in all 6 frames.

By "non-productive" I mean those that don't translate into proteins (don't have the amino acid M and/or have too many stop codons). I would like to filter out these non-productive sequences in a fasta file.

As for the "productive" ones, I would also like to save every "productive" sequence only with the complete frame in another fasta file.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as asking for recommendation for tools is against the site rules - it tends to lead to opinion-based answers and arguments.   I'd say one of the most important questions is who is the data going to be used by?   It there are multiple packages you could use, then picking the one most compatible with the next step in the process would likely make sense.

Comment: Hello! I'm new here, and I'm a recent Bioinformatics graduate, so programming is not my strong point at the moment... I asked if there was any tool to do this because it would be the quickest and easiest for me right now... 
As for programming I know that using some loops etc can be done, but I'm still struggling to program, so any ideas are welcome...

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56939/do-all-proteins-start-with-methionine Do all proteins start with methionine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example using [`biopython`](https://biopython.org) and a threshold on the number of stop codons.

```
# pip install biopython
from Bio import SeqIO

seqs = SeqIO.parse(open('example.fasta'), 'fasta')
productive = {}
for s in seqs:
    productive.setdefault(s.count('*')<3, []).append(s)

print(productive)
```

Output:

```
{True:  [SeqRecord(seq=Seq('HSTSDSAQTMFPVALLLLAAGSCVKGEQLTQPTSVTVQPGQRLTITCQVSYSLG...FPL'), id='abc', name='abc', description='abc', dbxrefs=[])],
 False: [SeqRecord(seq=Seq('TARQIQHKPCFL*LCCCWQLDHV*RVNS*HSRPL*LCSQVNV*PSPVRSLILLV...FL*'), id='def', name='def', description='def', dbxrefs=[]),
         SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GSQHVRFSTNHVSCSSAAVGSWIMCEG*TVDTADLCDCAARSTSDHHLSGLLFS...VSS'), id='ghi', name='ghi', description='ghi', dbxrefs=[])]}
```

You can add a mode complex logic by replacing `s.count('*')<3` by a custom function:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

seqs = SeqIO.parse(open('test/stackoverflow/example.fasta'), 'fasta')

def is_productive(s) -> bool:
    # does the sequence start with M and contain less than 3 stops?
    return s.seq.startswith('M') and (s.count('*')<3)

productive = {}
for s in seqs:
    productive.setdefault(is_productive(s), []).append(s)
```

##### writing as fasta:

```
with open('productive_seqs.fasta', 'w') as fw:
    SeqIO.write(productive.get(True, []), fw, 'fasta')
with open('nonproductive_seqs.fasta', 'w') as fw:
    SeqIO.write(productive.get(False, []), fw, 'fasta')
```

Output:

```
# productive_seqs.fasta
>abc
HSTSDSAQTMFPVALLLLAAGSCVKGEQLTQPTSVTVQPGQRLTITCQVSYSLGTYFTAW
IRQPAGKGLEWIGMRSTGASYYKDSLKNKFSIDLDTSSKTVTLNGQNVQPEDTAVYYCAR
APSRGFDYWGKGTMVTITSATPKGPTVFPL

# nonproductive_seqs.fasta
>def
TARQIQHKPCFL*LCCCWQLDHV*RVNS*HSRPL*LCSQVNV*PSPVRSLILLVPTSQLG
SDSLQEKDWSGLE*DLLELHTTKIH*RTSSVST*TLPAKL*L*MDRMCSLKTLLCITVPE
RPVGVLTTGGKAPWSPSPRPPQRDQLCFL*
>ghi
GSQHVRFSTNHVSCSSAAVGSWIMCEG*TVDTADLCDCAARSTSDHHLSGLLFSW*LLHS
LDQTACRKRTGVDWEQIYWSCILQRFIKEQVQYRLRHFQQNCDSKWTECAA*RHCCVLLC
QTTGSGSWLLGERHHGHHHLGHPKGTNCVSS
```

Note that if you only need the files, you can directly write the sequence in the loop:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

seqs = SeqIO.parse(open('test/stackoverflow/example.fasta'), 'fasta')

def is_productive(s):
    return s.seq.startswith('M') and (s.count('*')<3)

with open('productive_seqs.fasta', 'w') as fw1, open('nonproductive_seqs.fasta', 'w') as fw2:
    for s in seqs:
        SeqIO.write(s, fw1 if is_productive(s) else fw2, 'fasta')
```

Comment: I thought of filtering out the "non-productive" ones first, which would not contain any "M". Then within the "productive" ones, filter out the ones with one M or maximum 2 and no more than three stop codons in the middle (limit of 10 amino acids at the beginning and at the end). Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @Silvia you can easily use nested conditions then: `if s.seq.startswith('M'): if (s.count('*')<3): # then file1 ; else: # file2 ; else: # file3`

Comment: I have been checking and many "productive" sequences are filtered out as "non-productive". The problem is that the M doesn't need to be right at the beginning of the sequence, it can be about 10 amino acids further on... how could I put that? I tried with s.seq.find('M'), a little bit better but not quite... Thanks!

Comment: for any position `'M' in s.seq`, for the first 10 amino-acids `'M' in s.seq[:10]`. For a `M` before the first `*`: `'M' in s.split('*')[0]`

Comment: Hi, I tried with `'M' in s.seq[:] and (s.count('*')<2)` and it's works very well. Thank you so much for your help!!